# Copying Image from URL to HTTP URL

Tags: java, image, http

Someone is providing a S3 Presigned URL so that I can upload my images to that link. All my images are on the website. Is there a way in JAVA to copy the image URL to the new URL provided ?

I am trying to do this. Seems like an overkill

```
try {

        // Get Image from URL
        URL urlGet = new URL("http://something.com/something.png");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(urlGet);

        //for png
        ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("/something.png"));

        // for jpg
        //ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("/something.jpg"));

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        byte[] imageInBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        outputStream.close();

            URL url = new URL(putUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
            connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, PNG_MIME_TYPE);
            OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();

            try {
                stream.write(imageInBytes);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            switch (connection.getResponseCode()) {
                case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                    return "";
                default:
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occured", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: *"Seems like an overkill"* Yes. You should not use `ImageIO` to copy files (even if they are image files). Just use normal stream/channel copy. Using an in-memory or on-disk buffer probably makes sense, especially for large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no point converting to BufferedImage and back for the copy when you can preserve the byte stream of the original files. The first part can be replaced with simple call to extract the bytes off your website:

```
byte[] imageInBytes = read(urlGet);
```

Where `read()` is:

```
private static byte[] read(URL url) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16*1024);
    try (var in = url.openStream()) {
        in.transferTo(out);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

If you use JDK11 onwards you could try the HttpClient class for the GET and POSTs, for example this does same as above if passing it `urlGet.toURI()`:

```
private static byte[] read(URI uri) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(uri).build();
    var resp = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
    return resp.body();
}
```